# Validate process id (start/stop tomcat) if multiple tomcat running on same VM

Tags: java, tomcat

I want my alfresco tomcat to be restarted after patching activity. but issue is sometime if multiple tomcat running on same host, my script fails to identify which tomcat to start/stop. How do I identify unique tomcat on linux and start appropriate?

I tried below

```
isTomcatRunning()
{

 pid=$(ps ax | grep "$alfrescoHomePath"  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

 if [ "${pid}" ] && [ "$actualAlfrescoRunning" == "$expectedAlfrescoProcess" ]; 
 then
    return 0        
 else
    return 1
fi
}
```

Where

```
actualAlfrescoRunning=$(ps -elf | grep java | grep /tomcat/bin | awk '{print $15}')
```

And

```
expectedAlfrescoProcess=$alfrescoHomePath/java/bin/java
```

Still it is failing.
Anyone help me identify my unique process apart from multiple java or tomcat.

Comment: You should setup your tomcat servers as services, then you can simply use `service tomcatAlfresco status|start|stop|restart`.

Comment: Yes I can understand that, but due to initial setup, it is planned like to start manually. And we can have multiple tomcat on single VM. it is redhat 6 and 7 VM host.

Comment: In that case, just take a look at tomcat's service script and see how they do it. They most probably have a function to determine if there is any running instance.